# Light source problem 2.79

Tags: lighting

[image: unknown light source]

While trying to apply a fixed lamp and moving sun to an animation (to see the effects of different lights from different angles) I noted that neither seemed to be affecting my texture when rendering (Cycles), but instead there was an unknown, invisible light source from directly above. It's not something I put there. I set up a kind of sundial needle which indicated the light's directional origin.
I'm still learning the Principled BSDF and can't get the spotlight and sun to take effect, but have only the other uncontrollable source.
Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you've left the world Diffuse option enabled in the Properties panel > World > Ray Visibility?

Comment: Is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599)?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the worls ray visibility settings but they don't fix the problem - thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm new to this site. Where and how does one upload the .blend ?

Comment: @IanRoos Sorry, I didn't see your response (you can tag people with `@<username>` when replying to comments to make sure they get notified). As for where to upload .blends, we prefer [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). (see the [meta question from my previous comment](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599))